# Invoking a script whenever ip monitor writes into stdout

Tags: python, bash, stdout

I would like to run `ip monitor` in the background and invoke a script whenever a new block of output is sent to `stdout` by `ip monitor` (or, ideally, if there are several new blocks sent within say 3 seconds, only invoke the script once)

I would like to use `bash` or `python`, but I'm open to other suggestions as well.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Let's go with bash. Are you familiar with 1) piping a command's output to another command and 2) the `read` command?

Comment: 1) yes, and I use it frequently
2) not yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a *while loop* with `read` :

```
$ ip monitor all | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "CATCHED: $line";
    ./script "$line"
done
```

[bash FAQ#1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/01)

Or using [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs) :

```
ip monitor all | xargs -n1 ./script
```